# Ganglia csv export gives timestamp as 1970-01-01 but not current time

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, ganglia

Ganglia csv export gives time stamp as 1970-01-01. But when I view ganglia webfrontend, it shows proper time. I check Ganglia-webfrontend code, it shows that it is getting this value from RRDtool. Any solution to this.

Ganglia Web Frontend version 3.6.1
Ganglia Web Backend (gmetad) version 3.6.0.
RRDtool version 1.5.4

[Edit1]

Sample of csv exported file from my cluster :

```
Timestamp,1-min,Nodes,CPUs ,Procs  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
1970-01-01T05:30:00+05:30,16:08:20 03:29:01,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Sample of csv exported file from https://ganglia.wikimedia.org/latest/ :

```
Timestamp,In ,Out  
2016-08-20T12:00:15+00:00,12849582.909,311121.67333  
2016-08-20T12:00:30+00:00,12872902.147,360193.53067  
2016-08-20T12:00:45+00:00,12774903.844,365818.67533  
2016-08-20T12:01:00+00:00,12748911.431,383361.00133  
2016-08-20T12:01:15+00:00,12759820.237,390467.666  
2016-08-20T12:01:30+00:00,12914302.844,389208.29267  
2016-08-20T12:01:45+00:00,12938113.925,372756.31267
```

Ganglia wiki gives latest timestamp but the one installed on my cluster gives 1970-01-01. So this means Ganglia has the feature to display latest timestamp but one install on my cluster doesn't support this feature. But this is the latest ganglia version I could get using apt-get. There is Ganglia-3.7.2 available but it is not install able using apt-get and facing some issue while installing using rpm. Any help

[Edit2]

When I check the Ganglia version on Ganglia-wiki, this is the version I found. Only difference is with the rrdtool version.
Ganglia Web Frontend version 3.6.1
Ganglia Web Backend (gmetad) version 3.6.0.
RRDtool version 1.4.7

Comment: Clearly, as 1970-01-01 is a time value of '0', there is some sort of bug in the Ganglia extract routines.  However without knowledge of the ganglia internals I cant say what the exact problem is.  You might like to note if this happens with ALL databases, or just one of them?  Can you post a sample of the exported data, or the RRD info?  This might help people duplicate and track down your problem.

Comment: Ganglia uses rrdtool as its database. I don't know if it support other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after installation of rrdtool-1.4.7-1

Step to install rrdtool-1.4.7:
1)Downlaod .deb file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/rrdtool/1.4.7-1
2)Goto to download directroy
3)sudo dpkg -i rrdtool_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb